# Function not executing in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I have a function, that fills column in `DataGridView` with student name and student surname merged from students table, depending on student Id, that is found in the table, in which that column i mentioned earlier is located.

The function is:

```
public void replace_namesSurnames()
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in attendance_dgw.Rows)
            {
                int student_id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["student_id"].Value);
                if (row.Index < attendance_dgw.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    string text = attendanceRecording.Tables["students"].Rows[student_id - 1]["student_name"].ToString() + " " + attendanceRecording.Tables["students"].Rows[student_id - 1]["student_surname"].ToString();
                    row.Cells["stud_nameSurname"].Value = text;
                }
            }
        }
```

If i execute this function from a button click, it works. It works when initializing form for the first time as well.

I've tried to add a `CellValueChanged` event to that `DataGridView` but the function does not execute:

```
        private void attendance_dgw_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            replace_namesSurnames();
        }
```

Is there any fix for this? I really dont see any problems here.

Comment: Have you subscribed to that grids event?...  `attendance_dgw.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(attendance_dgw_CellValueChanged);`

Comment: If the grids underlying data source is a `DataTable`, then, you may consider using an `Expression` column. [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0) … This would eliminate the `replace_namesSurnames` method altogether. The column definition with the `Expression` string may look something like… `attendanceRecording.Tables["students"].Columns.Add("stud_nameSurname", typeof(string), " student_name + ' ' + student_surname");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so my friend helped me to find the solution.

First of all, i forgot to mention, that the main purpose of this function was, to change Name Surname accordingly to changed student_id. BUT! Change of student ID is happening with help of separate form.

So the main problem (why this all started) was, that function, which is updating those Name Surname values was located in the main form, but I was executing it from the form, which changes the student ID.

In form, which changes student ID, I made an main form object, to access functions from that main form. But, it seems that program wasn't seeing, what is inside that function, and that was the reason, why it did not execute.

So, the fix is-
Passing the main form to the form which makes changes.

```
detailsTableForm details = new detailsTableForm(attendanceRecording, cellValue,e.RowIndex,e.ColumnIndex,0,columnName,attendance_dgw, this);
```

The main focus there, is on passing "this" (the main form) to the "detailsTableForm" (form, that makes changes to student ID in main form).
When I passed "this" (the main form) to the "detailsTableForm", I then assigned that received form to form object in "detailsTableForm" and then it all worked.